# Exporting procedure result from Oracle to Postgres

Tags: database, oracle, postgresql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have an Oracle database that has some tables. I need to migrate the table entries from Oracle to Postgres database. My goal is to write a procedure in PL/SQL that would take an ID as an input parameter. For that ID it would generate an SQL script that adds the required columns (from oracle db) into the Posgres db. How can I export the SQL code from Oracle to Postgres?

Comment: You could output your Oracle data to a file, input it with the Postgres `copy` or psql `\copy` command. The whole operation could probably be scripted.

Comment: I need to export it as a script file that I would run on Postgres. How would I do that in oracle SQL developer?

Comment: Postgres doesn't run PL/SQL exactly, it has its own variant called PL/pgsql. See http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/interactive/plpgsql-porting.html As for getting it out of Oracle, see the tables `all_source`, `user_source` and `dba_source`.

Comment: Try pulling data from PostgreSQL using Foreign Data Wrappers. You can access Oracle using this. http://laurenz.github.io/oracle_fdw/